# Changing the relative position of the starting point of every chapter (also Preface, References, Index if any)

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I would like that the starting point of the first page of each chapter (also Preface, References, Index if any) be at the position 1/3 of the text-height of the page (from the top of the page). In other words in the following document I would like that the word `Chapter 1` starts just after 1/3 of the page-height from the top.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{one}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution:using `titlesec` package

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{.33\textheight}{40pt}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{one}

\end{document}
```

Second solution:using `etoolbox` package

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{.33\textheight}}{}{\errmessage{fail in patching \noexpand\@makechapterhead command}}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{.33\textheight}}{}{\errmessage{fail in patching \noexpand\@makeschapterhead command}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{one}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I confirm that your second solution with `etoolbox` works perfect. Your first solution (with `titlesec`) has some conflicts with the packages I use, I am investigating the issue. Thank you very much.